# External login not working in asp.net mvc using Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I´m trying to implement a Google login in a ASP.NET MVC application using [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/874626/MVC-and-Identity-Framework-Part?fid=1878773&df=90&mpp=50&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&view=Normal&fr=12) but once I logged in I noticed that `Request.IsAuthenticated = false`. Here is my code. This is almost the same code I used for facebook and facebook login worked very well.

```
       const string GoogleClaimBaseName = "urn:google:{0}"; 
       string GoogleClaimProfile = String.Format(GoogleClaimBaseName, "profile");
       string GoogleClaimSub = String.Format(GoogleClaimBaseName, "sub");
       string GoogleClaimName = String.Format(GoogleClaimBaseName, "name");       
       string googleClientId = "Id";

        string googleClientSecret = "Secret";

        var googleAuthenticationOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = googleClientId,
            ClientSecret = googleClientSecret,

            Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = async googleContext =>
                {
                    string profileClaimName = string.Format(GoogleClaimBaseName, "profile");

                    foreach (JProperty property in googleContext.User.Children())
                    {
                        var claimType = string.Format(GoogleClaimBaseName, property.Name);
                        string claimValue = (string)property.Value;
                        if (!googleContext.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                            googleContext.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(claimType, claimValue, xmlSchemaString, "External"));
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        googleAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
        googleAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleAuthenticationOptions);
```

The problem begins when I tried to get Google's profile information. Before that, everything was working fine.

Comment: Couple of things, 1. Post any error logs in the middleware, 2. In the call back, are you able to get the external identity

Comment: there are no logs errors... just logged in and Request.IsAuthenticated is still false...

Comment: Are you behind any firewall. Also check out the output Windows for any hints if any

Comment: The problem begins when I tried to get Google's profile information. Before that, everything was working fine.

Comment: I think that it is the cause of firewall, because, i too had such an issue while the other requests being browser redirections, the profile is an internal one and hence it may be blocked with the firewall. Try to use the console application or one such to first check if the api calls are working fine. this is more similar to that of the google oauth2 playground